# Does ros have any messages and/or tools for displaying histograms?

Tags: ros, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I can tell the answer is no. But I didn't want to reproduce anything if it already existed or if there was a clever combination of tools/msgs that I wasn't sharp enough to think up.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10004/does-ros-have-any-messages-and/or-tools-for-displaying-histograms?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never come across anything in ROS itself but assuming you've installed the `rxtools` package (`rx` stack) then you have `matplotlib` installed since it's a dependency (used by `rxplot`) and you can use its [pyplot.hist](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) command.

As for how to get the data to plot, there are lots of ways but you're looking for a quick, one-off solution you could use `rosh` (you probably want to check [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosh/Overview/Topics) for usage details). It could look something like this though:

```
# pop up a histogram of the field `bar` from the 
# last 100 messages on the topic `foo`:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.array([m.bar for m in topics.foo[:100]])
plt.hist(x)
plt.show()
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5